# Should the extension of built-in Javascript prototypes through symbols also be avoided?

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-6, symbols

It is the [predominant opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) that built-in Javascript prototypes should not be extended (or altered in any way):

```
Array.prototype.empty = function () { return this.length === 0; } // don't try that
```

Does this rule also apply to ES2015 symbols?

```
const empty = Symbol("empty");
Array.prototype[empty] = function empty() { return this.length === 0; }
```

Since `symbol` is a mix of `string` (primitive, immutable) and `object` (identity) there can be no object property naming conflicts by definition.

Normal object reflection is not affected by symbols:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype).indexOf("empty"); // -1
```

But ES2015 reflection with `Reflect.ownKeys(Array.prototype)` is.

So this question is mainly about how we'll use `Reflect.ownKeys` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` in the future.

Comment: Don't forget you can subclass built-ins now, so there's one more reason not to extend the prototypes of built-ins

Comment: @RGraham The main reason why I have asked this question is to get a better understanding of use cases or edge cases of symbols, since they are a relatively new feature. I think I won't actually extend built-ins' prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There are two parts to the "don't modify something you don't own" rule:

1. You can cause name collisions and *you* can break *their* code.

   By touching something you don't own, you may accidentally overwrite something used by some other library. This will break their code in unexpected ways.
2. You can create tight dependencies and *they* can break *your* code.

   By binding your code so tightly to some other object, if they make some significant change (like removing or renaming the class, for example), your code might suddenly break.

Using symbols will avoid #1, but you still run into #2. Tight dependencies between classes like that are generally discouraged. If the other class is ever [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), your code will still break. The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242/129032) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) still apply, just for slightly different reasons.

You want to focus on [loosely binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) your dependencies to support better testing (loose bindings are easier to mock) and easier maintenance (a few obvious connections are easier to document and update).

To be clear: the name collisions are just a symptom of the problems caused by tightly-bound dependencies.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt ES6 or classic prototypes, the impact is the same. You're creating a two-way dependency on something without a contract. Using `String.prototype.substr` is a safe, one-way dependency: you use the function, they provide a contract stating it will exist and how it will behave. Injecting something into `String.prototype` is more round-about (you both modify and use them) and they typically don't provide a contract saying that will remain possible.

Comment: In the end, this boils down to "that could be dangerous, don't touch it." While that will make real life boring, it makes code *stable*.

Comment: But if you create an instance of Array.prototype and then make it immutable (freeze), `push` and `pop` etc. are broken too. Can you give another specific example?

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Not freezing the instance, freezing the class. They can also remove a class, rename it, require it be imported, or anything else that changes the visibility. Any unexpected changes have the potential to break your code.

Comment: While I take your examples for too general and unlikely (at least in the context of Javascript), I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: @IvenMarquardt it's not a very good example, but I'm drawing a blank on anything else. :( If you find something better, by all means suggest an answer edit!

Comment: IMO, this answer is not answering the question. For #2, upgrading any basic APIs will break any code. This is in principle that no one can avoid. Since this is unanswered,I created Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505938/is-object-freezeobject-prototype-only-the-hazard-for-extending-object-proto.

Comment: Not a good answer, if someone would freeze built-in class, say Array it's their problem, such cases are so tiny that could be ignored.