# Javascript: Augment a standard class without global prototype changes

Tags: javascript, prototype

A classic "[bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)" in JS is to alter the prototypes of inbuilt types:

```
Array.prototype.last = function() { return this[this.length - 1] }; 
[1,2,3].last() // 3
```

In ES6 we can extend the inbuilt Array type:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  last() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}
```

But there's no great way to add these functions without copying:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = new MyArray(...a);
// [1, 2, 3]
b === a 
// False
```

[We can update the object's prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat):

```js
a = [1, 2, 3]
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, MyArray.prototype);
a.last() // 3
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, Array.prototype);
a.last() // TypeError
```

However, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> Warning: Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine.

Helper functions or container classes can help, but their syntax is unwieldy:

```js
ArrayHelper.last(a); // 3
MyArrayWrapper(a).last(); // 3
MyArrayWrapper.get(0); // Ugh, we lose []-based indexing.
```

The ideal solution would be something like:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = asMyArray(a);
b.last(); // 3
a.last(); // TypeError

// But avoid doing a copy, and have both objects reference the same memory:
b[0] = 10; 
a[0] == 10; // true
```

or, if it's easier

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
applyMyArrayPrototype(a);
a.last(); // 3
a.dropMyArrayPrototype();
a.last(); // TypeError
```

Is there a way to achieve this in JS?

Comment: Why not just `a.last = MyArray.prototype.last`?

Comment: @Barmar Hm, that might be the best way to go, yeah.

Comment: Another solution for `asMyArray()` is for it to return a proxy object, so it can share storage with the original array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366031/implement-array-like-behavior-in-javascript-without-using-array

Comment: Consider [using `Symbol`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749640/should-the-extension-of-built-in-javascript-prototypes-through-symbols-also-be-avoided)

Comment: "*`MyArrayWrapper(a).get(0)` ugh, we lose []-based indexing.*" - can't you just use `a[0]` directly in that place? Or `MyArrayWrapper(a).get()[0]`?

Comment: @Barmar `a.last = MyArray.prototype.last` is as bad as assigning to `Array.prototype.last` directly, assuming you receive `a` from other code or want to pass `a` to other code.

Comment: @Bergi, certainly we can use `wrapper.arr[0]`, yeah. Using helper-functions or a wrapper class is not a terrible inconvenience, I just wanted to check if there was a "better way".

Comment: @Kaia I think every other "better" way that makes `a` and `b` less distinguishable (like the `Proxy` "wrapper" approach) or even identical (augmenting the instance or its prototype with the methods) will run into the same issues that are the reason it's considered a bad idea.